# How to storage an array local in a packaged chrome app?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, google-chrome-app

how to write this:

```
localStorage.setItem("storageArray", array);//save array
```

with chrome.storage.local.set() for a Chrome packadged app and how to write this:

```
try {
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.getItem("results").split(",").length; i++) {
        array[i] = localStorage.getItem("storageArray").split(",")[i];//get saved array
    }
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
```

with chrome.storage.local.get()?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet (didn't actually test it, but based on the docs [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html), it should work):

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'myobjkey': theValue}, function() {
    alert('object saved');
});
...
chrome.storage.local.get('myobjkey', function(items) {
    alert('here are my objects');
    for (var key in items) {
        alert(key + ' = ' + JSON.stringify(items[key]));
    }
});
```

Comment: It does not work. This is my code: `chrome.storage.local.set({'results': results}, function () {});       chrome.storage.local.get('results', function (items) {
        for (var key in items) {
            results[key] = items[key];
        }
    });`

Comment: you must synchronize the instructions. the 'set' instruction runs asynchronously, that's why you pass a function callback to be execute upon completion. Try this:
`chrome.storage.local.set({'results': results}, function () { chrome.storage.local.get('results', function (items) { for (var key in items) { results[key] = items[key]; } }); });`

Comment: That does not work too, but I have found the solution: `chrome.storage.local.set({'results': results}); chrome.storage.local.get('results', function (items) {
        results = items['results'];
    });`

Comment: which is the solution i've given, since the error was on how you were iterating through the result. please mark it as the right solution. thanks. cheers

Answer (score -1):

You need to serialize the Array by Using

```
localStorage.setItem("storageArray", JSON.stringify(Array));
```

Later if you fetch the data from local Storage you just need to parse the data with

```
var aArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storageArray"));
```

Comment: That does not work. Also I want it for a chrome packaged app. LocalStorage.setItem() does not work in chrome packaged apps. You need to use chrome.storage.local.set(). But I do not know how to use it.